# Excel VBA: how to apply bold format to all words before ":"?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to apply the bold format to all words before a colon (:) in a specific cell. In the image, the words first / second / third need to be in bold, the rest not.

[image: example]

I found the following code on a different thread, but it applies the bold format to the first word before a colon.

```vb
Sub PreColon()
    Dim i As Long, N As Long, s As String, j As Long

    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To N
        s = Cells(i, 1)
        j = InStr(1, s, ":")
        If j <> 0 Then
            Cells(i, 1).Characters(1, j - 1).Font.Bold = True
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

split on the `-` and do a second loop:

```
Sub PreColon()
    With ActiveSheet

        Dim N As Long
        N = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        
        Dim i As Long
        For i = 1 To N
            Dim strLen As Long
            strLen = 0
            
            Dim sArray() As String
            sArray = Split(.Cells(i, 1), "-")
            Dim s As Variant
            For Each s In sArray
                Dim j As Long
                j = InStr(s, ":")
                If j > 0 Then
                    .Cells(i, 1).Characters(strLen + 1, j - 1).Font.Bold = True
                End If
                strLen = strLen + Len(s) + 1
            Next s
        Next i
    End With
                    
        
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a little procedure you can use:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim i As Long, N As Long
    
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To N
        FormatPreColon Cells(i, 1)
    Next
End Sub

Sub FormatPreColon(Rng As Range)
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    
    If TypeName(Rng.Value) <> "String" Then Exit Sub
    
    i = InStr(1, Rng, ":")
    Do While i <> 0
        j = InStrRev(Rng, " ", i) + 1
        Rng.Characters(j, i - j).Font.Bold = True
        i = InStr(i + 1, Rng, ":")
    Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible missing "-" symbol you may use this.

```
Dim i As Long, s As String, j As Integer, k As Integer, t As String, counter As Integer, N As Integer

N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
For i = 1 To N
    s = Cells(i, 1)
    j = 1
    k = 1
    Do While j > 0
        j = InStr(k, s, ":")
        k = j + 1
        counter = 1
        For m = j - 1 To 1 Step -1
            t = Trim(Mid(s, m, 1))
            If (t = "" Or m = 1) Then
                Cells(i, 1).Characters(m, counter).Font.Bold = True
                Exit For
            Else
                counter = counter + 1
            End If
        Next m
    Loop
    DoEvents
Next i
MsgBox "Finito..."
```